# SQL Syntax Error when using primary key with WHERE

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use UPDATE with my MySQL-Database. I use the following SQL code:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE ToDo 
    SET Checked = -1
    WHERE Index = 1";
```

When I use this code i get the following error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index = 1' at line 3"

But when I use

```
$sql =  "UPDATE ToDo 
    SET Checked = -1
    WHERE Text = 'asdf'";
```

Everything works.

My database has one table named "ToDo" with 3 collumns: Index(int, primary key, auto_increment), Checked(bool) and Text(text).

Can't you "WHERE" a primary key or did i forget something else?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the backticks:

```
UPDATE ToDo 
    SET `Checked` = -1
    WHERE `Index` = 1";
```

Index is a reserved word :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 5):

`index` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL. You need to esacpe the name by adding backticks like this:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE ToDo 
SET Checked = -1
WHERE `Index` = 'asdf'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure MySQL understands that you are talking about a column name and not the reserved word, you can always address the column name tablename.columnname.
In SELECT queries also using shortcuts is possible:

`UPDATE ToDo SET ToDo.Checked = -1 WHERE ToDo.Index = 1`
`SELECT u.Index FROM users u`

Also I would recommend not to use camel cases in tables and columns. This proved to be a source for errors and has no real benefit most of the time.

Answer (score -2):

Boolean is 0 or 1, not -1. Try using 0 or 1 for Checked and let us know what happens.

Comment: That is not even true. `BOOLEAN` and `BOOL` are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`, which has a value range of -128 to +127. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Wow. It's been a long day already to say the least... Maybe I should quit while I'm ahead.

Comment: Please check yourself before you post answers like these.

Comment: @Jaime, It happens. I used to think it was a true boolean as well.